# How to shift the leftmost item of the Bootstrap navigation bar to further left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, bootstrap-4

I've created a Bootstrap navigation bar and below that, I have made a container in which I will show some description as shown in the image below. I've used the latest version of the bootstrap.

[image]

Now, the alignment of the description text should match that of the left-most item of the navigation bar, but what I'm getting from my code is shown in the below image.

[image]

Here you can clearly see that the alignment of the left most navbar item i.e. CP-210-1 button doesn't match with the description text starting with **This is...**.

Here is my code.

```css
.model-family-navigation-bar {
  background-color: #00853e;
}

.navigation-bar-content {
  color: white;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.dropdown-menu>div>a:hover {
  background: #8dc4d4;
}

.dropdown-menu>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #d9d9d9;
}

.dropdown-menu>div:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f9fffe;
}

.border-section {
  border: 2px solid #D0D0D0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.greenTitle {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

  a:link {
    
    font-size: 120%;
    background-color: transparent; 
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App5</title>
  <base href="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container model-family-navigation-bar" style="min-height: 32px">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark model-family-navigation-bar" style="min-height: 32px">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <!-- <div class="col-sm-auto"> -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle navigation-bar-content text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="text-decoration:none">
              <span id="selected" style="text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold">CP-210-1</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" style="background-color:#00853e">
              <h1 class="dropdown-header text-white">Model Family</h1>
              <div>
                <!-- <div class="dropdown-divider"></div> -->
                <a class="dropdown-item text-black" (click)="showList()">CP210-1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-black" (click)="showList()">CP210-2</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-black" (click)="showList()">CP210-3</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-black" (click)="showList()">CP210-4</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <!-- </div> -->
          <!-- <div class="col-sm-auto"> -->
          <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navigation-bar-content navbar-text text-white ml-4">Proportional Directional Valve</span>
          </li>
          <!-- </div> -->
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="https://www.google.com/" style="font-size:13px">Data Sheet</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="container border-section mt-2">
    <div class="row" style="min-height:80px;">
      <p class="ml-4 mt-1" style="font-size:20px">This is a proportional, 3 position 4 way, directional control valve</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm not finding any way to align the left-most item of the navigation bar to the description text. Although I have an alternative to add the left padding to the left item but that's not what I'm supposed to do. So, can anyone help me out on how to align the text with the button item? Also, I'm not finding any way to decrease the height of the green colored navigation bar container equal to that as given in the first image.

If I decrease the height then the responsive behavior is not there on decreasing the browser width. So, can anyone suggest something for that also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix you could try setting the left padding of the "nav-link" anchor to 0.

Something like this:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link.dropdown-toggle {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Or you could add a custom class to that element and use that in your selector.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you provide some solution regarding the height issue also? How to make the height of the navigation bar equal to the first image navigation bar, restoring the responsive behavior?

Comment: Could you post the code for the first part? I could then compare the two.

Comment: You could try removing the "nav-link" class on the links and "nav-text" class on the text item. That will remove the upper and lower padding and might make it look the way you want it to. As an alternative you can remove the upper and lower padding from the "navbar" class.